# Find unique data from json using android

Tags: android, json

How to fetch unique results from json response using andorid.

Hi, i need to fetch data from json webservice, i have read all data's in the json. but i need to store unique value from json.

Is it possible to fetch unique value from json?

Comment: Show the code that you have done so far and the sample `JSON`.

Comment: what is the value in json???

Comment: Here is my sample json code                                                                       {
lastyear: [
{
order: "96 36 08",
year: "2015",
Text: "No"
},
{
order: "03 59 03",
year: "2014",
Text: "No"
},
{
order: "16 50 58",
year: "2014",
Text: "No"
}                                                                                                                      ]}   - I need the value for year as - OUTPUT - { 2015 , 2014 }

Answer (score 1):

pls try this code

```
    private void readJson(JSONObject jobj) {
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONArray jsonArray = jobj.getJSONArray("lastyear");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String year=obj.getString("year");
        if (!list.contains(year)) {
            list.add(year);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("FirstActivity.readJson()"+list);
}
```

Comment: output is - {2015,2014,2014}

Answer (score 1):

First, json is malformated:

```
{ "lastyear": [ { "order": "96 36 08", "year": "2015", "Text": "No" }, { "order": "03 59 03", "year": "2014", "Text": "No" }, { "order": "16 50 58", "year": "2014", "Text": "No" } ]}
```

To parse this array, you need implement like this

```
import org.json.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyObject {

private ArrayList<Lastyear> lastyear;


public MyObject () {

}   

public MyObject (JSONObject json) {


    this.lastyear = new ArrayList<Lastyear>();
    JSONArray arrayLastyear = json.optJSONArray("lastyear");
    if (null != arrayLastyear) {
        int lastyearLength = arrayLastyear.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < lastyearLength; i++) {
            JSONObject item = arrayLastyear.optJSONObject(i);
            if (null != item) {
                this.lastyear.add(new Lastyear(item));
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        JSONObject item = json.optJSONObject("lastyear");
        if (null != item) {
            this.lastyear.add(new Lastyear(item));
        }
    }


}

public ArrayList<Lastyear> getLastyear() {
    return this.lastyear;
}

public void setLastyear(ArrayList<Lastyear> lastyear) {
    this.lastyear = lastyear;
}



}
```

And the sub-object:

```
import org.json.*;


public class Lastyear {

private String order;
private String year;
private String text;


public Lastyear () {

}   

public Lastyear (JSONObject json) {

    this.order = json.optString("order");
    this.year = json.optString("year");
    this.text = json.optString("Text");

}

public String getOrder() {
    return this.order;
}

public void setOrder(String order) {
    this.order = order;
}

public String getYear() {
    return this.year;
}

public void setYear(String year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public String getText() {
    return this.text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}



}
```

How to use it:

```
MyObject object = new MyObject(new JSONObject("YOUR_JSON"));
//Verifiy if object.getLastyear != null
int sizeList = object.getLastyear().size;

for(int i = 0; i < sizeList;i++){
    LastYear lastYear = object.getLastyear().get(i)
    Log.e("App",lastYear.getYear);
}
```

To have only unique value, you can use :

```
private static String[] arrRemove(String[] strArray) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.addAll((List<String>) Arrays.asList(strArray));
    return (String[]) set.toArray(new String[set.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

parse the json into java and then use `HashSet yearHashSet` to store your years value.

traverse your array and then store it the `yearHashSet`.

In the end you will have only unique year values.